# Can't make my jar work after being built with intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to create a jar file from my project in Intellij IDEA and after building the artifact I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.trafficmonitoring.MatchPoint
```

I think that I have built the artifact correctly.

[Image showing the contents of the jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g85oq.png)

[Image showing project structure and Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFOJG.png)

[Image showing how the artifact was generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovuBT.png)

[Image showing the sbt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t77jA.png)

I can also see the MatchPoint class inside the jar as well as the manifest.

Any ideas of what could be going wrong?

The main method looks like this and it is scala/com/trafficmonitoring:

[Main method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjjbp.png)

It has to be said though, that I have several objects with main method inside scala/com/trafficmonitoring but when I create the artifact I clearly select one of them as the main class.

Comment: I just tried this with a simple project (https://github.com/scala/scala-seed.g8) and it works for me: https://pasteboard.co/HObj9TE.png. We need to see 1) contents of generated JAR 2) Your Intellij artifact setup

Comment: Also, do you insist on generating the runnable jar by using IntelliJ's artifacts ? SBT's assembly plugin can do the same for you.

Comment: Actually this question is missing all the crucial information about your problem. What does your build.sbt look like ? How are you generating your jar ? How are you trying to run your jar ?

Comment: Screenshot tells us exactly, how he is trying to run the jar. We can also deduce, that he is using IntelliJ jar artifact to generate the jar. But he needs to show us, how the artifact was defined and what are the contents of generated jar

Comment: I am also able to build a hello world jar but when I try to do the same with my project it doesn't work. And no, it doesn't necessarily need to be generated using IntelliJ but as I am not experienced with sbt I prefer using IntelliJ

Comment: Just rename the JAR to ZIP and show us, what is inside.

Comment: @ygor I have edited the question and now I show the contents of the jar

Comment: Well,  I am clueless.  please show us source code of the main class.  Is it a scala object?  With main method?  Or does it extend App?

Comment: @ygor I have provided a picture with the main class. It is a scala object and I don't extend App. I have to say though that I have several objects in my code with the main function. They are all in separate objects. But right now I'm just interested in MatchPoint

Comment: Everything seems legit. Maybe we can chat more here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184033/main-scala-class-not-found-in-intellij-artefact-jar

Comment: @ygor I can't access chatrooms yet ... :(